# how can I change the select tag position in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position, html-select

I’m working on a University Project

and I have a select tag

the problem is when the page is not in full Screen

the select position is perfect [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3MuO.png)

but when I’m full screen it doesn't appear like I want to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86m3Y.png)

```
Html Code
<div>

        <select class = "FeedBack2">
            <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
            <option value="Idea">Idea</option>
            <option value="Help">Help</option>
          </select>
    
    </div>
```

and here is The CSS Code

```
.FeedBack2 { background-color: #da9b48; color: rgb(31, 22, 5); width: 50%; margin-left:150px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px;}
```

Comment: So u want to fix select at midle of the page?

Comment: can u see the image I’ve upload with the question the problem is there..

Comment: Please clarify your question, because it's not clear what u want, or center option, or change width on full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
.FeedBack2 { 
display: flex;
background-color: #da9b48; 
color: rgb(31, 22, 5); 
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>

        <select class = "FeedBack2">
            <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
            <option value="Idea">Idea</option>
            <option value="Help">Help</option>
          </select>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to add the following to place select center horizontally and vertically. remove margin in.FeedBack2 class

```
div {
    display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-item: center;
 }
```